# Is there a material, man made or otherwise, that will 'absorb' visible light and 'reflect' non visible light?

Tags: waves

using the understanding that energy in any form cannot be indefinitely absorbed, in this case I speak of visible light. Is there a material\substance either man made or natural that will take visible light and convert\reflect it back as Ultra Violet light?

Comment: Did you see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation? A typical doubler crystal is KDP.

Answer (score 1):

Certain phosphors will work in that manner.  They will absorb 2 photons of visible light for every 1 photon they re-emit in the ultraviolet.